# Microsoft Graph Check user consent

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to know with Microsoft's GraphServiceClient how to check user consent/scope if possible.

Example I need that the current user in my C# app had consent to user.read and calendar.readwrite.shared, but I don't know how to check that.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your application has `client_id` (`application id`) stored in json configuration.

You can retrieve a list of [oAuth2PermissionGrant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-1.0) entities, which represent delegated permissions granted to a client application to access an API on behalf of the user like this

```
var oauth2PermissionGrants = await graphClient.Me.Oauth2PermissionGrants
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
var oauth2PermissionGrant = oauth2PermissionGrants
                             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == "{client_id_from_config}");
var scope = oauth2PermissionGrant.Scope;
```

Scope property is a space-separated list of the scope names.

Consent type property is set to `Principal` which indicates that those permissions are granted only to a specific user.

Permissions granted to all users are not listed here and you need to make another call to get permissions granted to all users for specific application.

```
var allOauth2PermissionGrants = await graphClient.Oauth2PermissionGrants
    .Request()
    .Filter("consentType eq 'AllPrincipals' and clientId eq '{client_id_from_config}'")
    .GetAsync();

var allOauth2PermissionGrant = oauth2PermissionGrants.FirstOrDefault();
var scope2 = allOauth2PermissionGrant.Scope;
```

You need `DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All` permission to for `/oauth2PermissionGrants` endpoint.

Now combine permissions from `scope` and `scope2` properties.

Comment: Thank, strange because I have all calendar righ in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer  (Calendars.Read, Calendars.Read.Shared Calendas.ReadWrite and Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared), but I only retrieve User.Read in my right ...

Comment: what do you mean by combine scope & scope2 ? Because in the allOauth2PermissonGrant, you only put the second scope rights. The first call is very requested, or the user consent can be just checked with the second oauth2PermissionGrants  request ?

Comment: Warning be I think I shouldn't use 'AllPrincipals' rights ? Because I don't use impersonation, but just base on a delegate client_id on a tenant and the current user's consent logged in my app